# .load function div php won't work?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to load a PHP file inside a div with this code:

editor.php:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("","",","");
$result = $con->query("SELECT title,id FROM Development ")or die("Error! : ".$con->error);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
    echo "<a href='#' id='edit-it' onclick=\"load('".$row['id']."');\">". $row['title']. "</a><br>";
};
```

Inside a JavaScript file:

```
function load(div,url)
{ 
    $('#edit-it').load('#title_edit_div','edit_title.php');
}
```

Inside the edit_title.php:

```
<?
$id=$_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
$result = $con->query("SELECT title,content, FROM Development  where id=".$id);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
    echo "<form action='" .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. "' method='get'> Title: <input type='text' name='title' value='",$row['title'],"><br>";
    echo "Content: <input type='text' name='content' value='",$row['content'],"><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Edit' name='change'></form>";
}
if(isset($_GET['change']))
{
    $con->query("UPDATE Development SET title=".$_GET['title'].", content=".$_GET['content']." WHERE id=".$id.";");
}
?>
```

And then back in editor.php:

```
echo "<div id='title_edit_div'></div>";
```

It just doesn't work. When I check the source code, all I get is:

```
<a id="edit-it" onclick="load('1');" href="#"></a>
```

How can I get the PHP file loaded inside the div?

Comment: Your syntax for `.load()` is wrong. It should be in the format `.load('ajax/test.html #container');`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Well it works so far. but when i press the <a href, it goes away, and it doesnt show the div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy example .. without database .. no JS

In index.php

```
<?php include_once 'page_labels.php'; ?>
<div>
   <?php pagelabel('HEADER'); ?>
</div>
```

In page_labels.php

```
function pagelabel($req)
{ 
    switch ($req)
    {
    case 'HEADER':
        echo '<a href="test.html">Test only</a>';
    case ..
    }
}
```

Comment: The case is, i need it with a database and JS. So your example is nice, but it doesnt do what i want it to do

Comment: About database .. you can changes `echo '<a href="test.html">Test only</a>';` with your database query .. I did it to fill my <li> and it work without JS ..